# issues installing pyvmomi on AlmaLinux 8

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pyvmomi, almalinux

Thanks for taking a look.

I have a clean installed AlmaLinux 8 machine and added the python3-pip, python3 and all dependencies installed. After that I want to install pyvmomi version 7.0.3 or 8.0.2 on to this system but on both versions I get the following error:

```
Command that i ran: 
pip3 install ./pyvmomi-7.0.3.tar.gz

Result:
Processing ./pyvmomi-7.0.3.tar.gz
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 565, in untar_file
tarfile.data_filter(member.replace(name=fn), location)
AttributeError: module 'tarfile' has no attribute 'data_filter'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 346, in run
requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 381, in prepare_files
ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 623, in _prepare_file
session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 810, in unpack_url
unpack_file_url(link, location, download_dir, hashes=hashes)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 716, in unpack_file_url
unpack_file(from_path, location, content_type, link)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 622, in unpack_file
untar_file(filename, location)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 566, in untar_file
except tarfile.LinkOutsideDestinationError:
AttributeError: module 'tarfile' has no attribute 'LinkOutsideDestinationError'
```

Do I miss a package? And if so, how can I see in the error what package I miss? (Using a local repo I need to download the latest version on another machine and make it available on the local repo).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `python3 --version`? `pip3 --version`? Function `data_filter()` was added to `tarfile` in Python 3.8. Your traceback indicates Python 3.6. Somehow you installed incompatible `pip`. First try to downgrade: `sudo python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. 
pip3 version: pip 9.0.3 from /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
I will have a try, but I can't go back to an older Python version as this is a security upgrade POC to go from Python 2 (where it still works) to a new setup with Python3, so somehow I need to get it working on python3

Comment: Indeed it was the incompatible pip3 version. I removed the also already outdated python3-pip (3.6.8) and installed python3.11-pip and now the installation of pyvmomi worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See result comment of user: phd, that pointed me in the right direction of an incompatible pip version.